# Running Javac Command with classpath on linux

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a folder Called TutorialFolder. Inside this, i have tutorial_class folder and `WordCount.java` file.
When I run wordcount program, it is giving below error.

```
hduser@ubuntu:~/Desktop/TutorialFolder$ javac -classpath ${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}-d '/home/hduser/Desktop/TutorialFolder/tutorial_class' '/home/hduser/Desktop/TutorialFolder/WordCount.java' 
javac: invalid flag: /home/hduser/Desktop/TutorialFolder/tutorial_class
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Comment: Typo. `${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}-d` should be `${HADOOP_CLASSPATH} -d`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Tried that . It is still giving same error :(

Comment: Is `'/home/hduser/Desktop/TutorialFolder/tutorial_class' ` your desired class destination  folder?

Comment: @delca85: Yes. It is the desired output folder.

Comment: And are you sure it already exists?

Comment: Yes . I have not manually typed this complete path. I have dragged and pasted it on terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with the variable `${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}` which is not set or empty. Thus the command is interpreted as,

```
javac -classpath  -d /home/hduser/Desktop/TutorialFolder/tutorial_class /home/hduser/Desktop/TutorialFolder/WordCount.java
```

Fix the `$HADOOP_CLASSPATH` variable, the command should work.

Or, Try with `hadoop classpath` command

```
javac -classpath `hadoop classpath` -d /home/hduser/Desktop/TutorialFolder/tutorial_class /home/hduser/Desktop/TutorialFolder/WordCount.java
```

Comment: How to fix this variable?

Comment: I checked by echoing ${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}. How to fix Classpath?

Comment: Add the variable to the `.bashrc` file like `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/:$CLASSPATH`.

Comment: Should I add this line in bashrc? 
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/hadoop/bin
:$CLASSPATH

Comment: No, that localtion is for the executables. Hadoop jar files are stored across multiple directories. Add all the folders as I have mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: Do I need to copy the same command you have mentioned as it is ?

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/:$HADOOP_H‌​OME/share/hadoop/com‌​mon/lib/:$HADOOP_HOM‌​E/share/hadoop/hdfs/‌​:$HADOOP_HOME/share/‌​hadoop/hdfs/lib/:$HA‌​DOOP_HOME/share/hado‌​op/yarn/:$HADOOP_HOM‌​E/share/hadoop/yarn/‌​lib/:$CLASSPATH

Comment: Is your hadoop installation done from tarball? And Do you have `$HADOOP_HOME` set, if yes You can try that. Or also, you can try the updated answer.

Comment: After this I am trying to execute by using this command: 
hadoop jar '/home/hduser/Desktop/TutorialFolder/firstTutorial.jar' WordCount /home/hduser/Desktop/TutorialFolder/input_data /TutorialFolder/Output

Below is the exception:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/home/hduser/Desktop/TutorialFolder/input_data
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:323)

Comment: This is a different error relating to the Input path you pass to the Wordcount code. The input and output paths must refer to HDFS. Post a new question on it, will be happy to help :))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458492/input-path-does-not-exists-while-running-wordcount-mapreduce