# Input path does not exists while running WordCount MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have installed a single node cluster on ubuntu.
I am trying to execute wordcount program. 
I have created jar file. 
But when I am going to execute this command:

```
hadoop jar '/home/hduser/Desktop/TutorialFolder/firstTutorial.jar' WordCount /home/hduser/Desktop/TutorialFolder/input_data /TutorialFolder/Output
```

It is giving below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: 
hdfs://localhost:9000/home/hduser/Desktop/TutorialFolder/inp‌​ut_data 
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.single‌​ThreadedListStatus(F‌​ileInputFormat.java:‌​323)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Input and Output paths given to mapreduce must be valid HDFS paths unless you are running Hadoop in local mode.

The Input path `/home/hduser/Desktop/TutorialFolder/input_data` passed here looks like a local directory. Create a similar structure in HDFS and upload the input data to that directory in HDFS.

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /wordcount/input_data
hdfs dfs -put /home/hduser/Desktop/TutorialFolder/input_data/ /wordcount/input_data/
```

Also the Output path must be in HDFS.
And Run the jar with the HDFS paths,

```
hadoop jar /home/hduser/Desktop/TutorialFolder/firstTutorial.jar WordCount /wordcount/input_data /wordcount/output
```

Comment: It worked thanks. Where do I need to navigate by clicking, to view data stored in hdfs.By command I know.

Comment: Go to `http://localhost:50070`, Select `Utilities --> Browse File System`, you should be able to view the folders created in HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on pseudo distributed mode, the input path must exist **on HDFS**, which doesn't have a Desktop folder...

Run some `hdfs dfs -ls /home/hduser` to inspect what's available, and put some files there

if that folder doesn't exist, you should maybe head back to your tutorials and setup HDFS.

Run `hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /home/hduser`

Note: you might get a permission denied error with that

Comment: ls: `/home/hduser/': No such file or directory

Comment: Yeah, exactly.  Your error isn't word count, it's not having HDFS setup... So run `hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /home/hduser`